# Events framework for Python?

Tags: python, events, twisted, message-queue

I'm building a system that works with web clients (Django) and remote APIs (probably a standalone daemon). I see it's easier to coordinate their work with some events framework like in JavaScript. Unfortunately, Django signals are synchronous, which will make replies to the clients very slow. Also, I might want to be able to migrate the daemon or its part to a separate machine, but still work the same way (not RPC, but just triggering an event or sending a message). (This might sound like Erlang's approach.)

Is there a framework that would use proven and reliable ways to communicate between processes (say, RabbitMQ), and require minimum boilerplate?

As for Twisted, that André Paramés suggested, I'd prefer a simpler code. Is this doable in Twisted?

```
from events_framework import subscribe, trigger
from django.http import Client
http_client = Client()  # just a sample

@subscribe('data_received'):
def reply(data):
     http_client.post('http://www.example.com', data)
     trigger('data_resent', data)
```

Here are more details. There is a Django views file that uses some models and notifies others of events. And there is a standalone daemon script that runs infinitely and reacts to events.

This is just **pseudo code**, I only mean how easy it should be.

```
# django_project/views.py (a Django views file)
from events_framework import publish, subscribe
from annoying import

@subscribe('settings_updated')
def _on_settings_update(event):  # listens to settings_updated event and saves the data
    Settings.object.get(user__id=event.user_id).update(event.new_settings)

@render_to('form.html')
def show_form(request):  # triggers 'form_shown' event
    publish('form_shown', {'user_id': request.user.id, 'form_data': request.GET})
    return {...}


# script.py (a standalone script)
from events_framework import publish, subscribe

@subscribe('form_shown')
def on_form_shown(event):  # listens to form_shown event and triggers another event
    pass
    result = requests.get('third party url', some_data)
    publish('third_party_requested', {'result': result})
```

Again, this couldn't be done just with Django signals: some events need to be published over network, others should be local but asynchronous.

It may be necessary to do instantiate something, like

```
from events_framework import Environment
env = Environment()  # will connect to default rabbitmq server from settings.
```

Comment: Why did you tag this `javascript`? It's not really related. As for an event-driven framework, have you seen [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)?

Comment: Removed the JS & Erlang tags...

Comment: Their hello world example made me scratch my head. How much boilerplate or weird code does it require?

Comment: What hello world example are you talking about?  This question really needs more detail.

Comment: @Glyph: Twisted has 3 examples in the documentation front page. Those I called hello world example.

Comment: You might have to read more than the examples on the front page to understand how to use Twisted.  Sorry, not all information in the universe can be condensed to 140 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) with [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is the most mature software combination, and I will stick with them. Celery allows not just creating events, but flexible specialization via [queue routing](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html), and [parallelization](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

Answer (score 6):

Check [circuits](https://circuitsframework.com/): a Lightweight Event driven and Asynchronous Application Framework for the Python Programming Language with a strong Component Architecture.

Comment: As the author of this library/framework I'm a little biased; nevertheless circuits is designed around a component architecture and event-driven message passing. --JamesMills / prologic

Answer (score 2):

[Django ztaskd](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask) is a way of calling asynchronous tasks from Django via ZeroMQ (via [pyzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq)).